# Copy between tmux sessions without including line numbers

Tags: vim, tmux, clipboard

When I try to copy and paste between tmux sessions or windows, one problem is that I usually have line numbers displayed when using Vim and tmux copies the line numbers:[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `set nonu`, or `"+y`...

Comment: or with more complication see what `vim-tmux-navigator` does; there may be a way to have `tmux save-bufer - | somethingthatstripsthenumbers` set when in `vim` under `tmux` (though that may require routing through the os clipboard, or a corresponding `tmux set-buffer` ...)

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` has the `rectangle-toggle` command for this.  It's not fully explained in the man page; it only appears in the list of commands available during copy mode:

> ```
> Command             vi      emacs
>                [...]
> rectangle-toggle    v       R
> ```

It switches between the line-based selection you demonstrate, and rectangular selection (similar to Vim's blockwise visual mode).  In the latter mode, you can start your selection at `static` and extend down+right without taking in anything to the left (the line numbers).

Comment: I can only seem to make this work with Emacs mod. When I do `C-b` then `:set-window-option -g mode-keys vi` then try the `C-b [` then `v` to `C-space`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @FilBot3 It works for me (tmux 3.1c). In vi mode the begin-selection binding is space rather than C-space, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl v` and then `v`, it works like vim block mode.

Demo: https://gitea.balki.me/balki/casts/src/branch/main/tmux_block_select.cast

```
❯ tmux -V
tmux 3.2a
```